# Cannot Bash chgrp GROUP /home/*/SOMEFILE/ How to do it?

Tags: cron, group, chmod

So am setting a code that will change group owner of the file to a specific group.

PS there are more than 10 users, with same folder and file structure, and i want change the ownership of a specific file in each folder.

So that if anyone edits the file, within 10 second (using `cron`, and `sleep` function) it will change the group owner to a specific group.

here is my code i used, and created a file named owner.sh

```
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
sleep 10
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
sleep 10
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
sleep 10
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
sleep 10
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
sleep 10
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
sleep 10
```

And it should work, but when I try to bash it,

```
bash owner.sh
```

it says that `/home/*/private/FILE.TXT` does not exist, but if I run it manually that is

```
chgrp www-data /home/*/private/FILE.TXT
```

, it goes in each and every user's folder and change the group of that specific file.

So how to make it work the way I want?

Comment: Ah. Where did you create this file? On a Windows PC?

Comment: I have updated. Please see now.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, using nano.

Comment: What's the output of running the command `file owner.sh` please? It should give one of two results. Either `owner.sh: ASCII text` or `owner.sh: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`.

Comment: Also, please provide the _exact and complete_ error message you get from running your script with `bash owner.sh`.

Comment: Do you have a `set -f ` somewhere in your bash startup scripts? check ~/.bashrc and/or ~/.bash_profile. It sounds as if you have globbing enabled in your current shell, but not in a stock bash startup.

Comment: Just a question, how a file group can change when one of your users edit it ? (I mean if he doesn't change explicitly the group of the file)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    for user in $(ls /home); do
        chgrp www-data /home/${user}/private/FILE.TXT
    done
    sleep 10
done
```

The infinite loop is for bypassing the cron limitation of 1 minute to repeat a job.
make it executable:

```
chmod +x /PATH/TO/owner.sh
```

And just run it without a cronjob.

Also if you just want to react to the modification of a file and modifying directly the ownership of this file, you can use the inotify-tools:

```
#!/bin/bash
for user in $(ls /home); do
    inotifywait -mqe close_write /home/${user}/private/FILE.TXT --format %f | while IFS= read -r file; do chgrp www-data $file; done
done
```

Just run it once